# How to hide a form element having a certain class in ajax callback in form?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

How can I hide the product using ajax callback . I am trying to implement that using ajax_commands_invoke but it does not work using below code

```
  $form['field_product_type_select']['und']['#ajax']= array('callback' => '_change_table_product_type','wrapper' => 'display-table-ajaxify');
 $header = array(
   'field_name' => t('Field Name'),
   'field_type' => t('Field Type'),
   'field_no_of_values' => t('Single/Multi Value'),
 );
 $options = array();

 foreach(commerce_product_types() as $product_type => $product_type_array){
   $field_info_instances = field_info_instances('commerce_product',$product_type);

   foreach($field_info_instances as $key => $value){
   $field_info_types = field_info_field_types($value['type']);
   $options[$key] = array(
     'field_name' => $value['label'],
     'field_type' => $field_info_types['label'],
     'field_no_of_values' => $value['cardinality'],
   );
  }

 $form['display_table'][$product_type] = array(
   '#type' => 'tableselect',
   '#options' => $options,
   '#header' => $header,
   '#multiple' => TRUE,
   '#prefix' => '<div class="display-'.$product_type.'" id="display-table-ajaxify" style="display:none;"><b>'.\
$product_type_array['name'].'</b>',
   '#suffix' => '</div>',
 );
 }

function _change_table_product_type(&$form,&$form_state){
  $commands = array();
  $product_type = $form_state['values']['field_product_type_select']['und'][0]['value'];
  drupal_set_message($product_type);
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('display-'.$product_type,'show');


  /* $product_type = $form_state['values']['field_product_type_select']['und'][0]['value']; */
  /* foreach ($form['display_table'] as $key => $value){ */
  /*   if ($key != $product_type) { */
  /*     unset($form['display_table'][$key]); */
  /*   } */

  /* } */
  //  return $form['display_table'][$product_type];
  //  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  print ajax_render($commands);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Commands are supposed to be returned in the callback function, not printed. Also, you have to give a CSS valid selector.

Try this:

```
function _change_table_product_type(&$form,&$form_state){
  $commands = array();
  $product_type = $form_state['values']['field_product_type_select']['und'][0]['value'];
  drupal_set_message($product_type);
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.display-' . $product_type, 'show');

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

}
```

You can show the actual selector that code generates and test it in the JavaScript console. Just type:

```
 jQuery('CSS_SELECTOR').show();
```

If element is shown your CSS selector code is right.